# Define "getting a value from the chip" vs. using a provided constant - assembly

Tags: assembly

I am preparing to start an assignment in C with a lot of embedded assembly code that I have to write. The program calculates the volume of a sphere using an inputted radius.

The instructions for one of the functions that needs to be written is to "write assembly code that gets the value of pi from the chip
instead of using the provided constant." That's all the function does. I'm unfamiliar with this terminology and would appreciate clarification on exactly what it means to "get something from the chip."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many FPUs today have constants stored in on-chip ROM for commonly used values (like pi certainly is). These can be loaded with special opcodes. For example, the opcode of the x86 FPU to load pi onto the FPU's register stack is `D9 EB` with a common mnemonic of `fldpi` (depending on your assembler, of course).

Look here for reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-5477/eoizy.html